# Are the latest Jepsen findings for ElasticSearch valid for the latest versions?

Tags: elasticsearch

There are some issues found by Jepsen in ElasticSearch years ago
https://aphyr.com/posts/323-call-me-maybe-elasticsearch-1-5-0 
Any ideas if they are still actual in recent Elastic versions?

Update: Elastic has a special approach to work on tickets by closing them without fix, linking duplicates with high nesting level and then closing them without fix or with partial fix. It's hard to trace if actual issue is really fixed or not.
For example this [ticket](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/2488) and all related.

With this approach it's very hard to understand what is fixed. I will keep this question open just in case somebody will be able to trace Elastic fixes of Jepsen issues.

Answer (score 2):

No, those findings are a long way out of date. There is a [page in the Elasticsearch manual](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/resiliency/current/index.html) that gives a good summary of the status of the issues found in that blog post and elsewhere.

Comment: The page you shared states some issues have "ONGOING" status and are not fixed.

Comment: The ONGOING issues do not relate to the Jepsen post you linked, except to note that this kind of testing is ongoing.

Comment: If they don’t relate to Jepsen, then why did you share them in your answer as a proof?

Comment: Part of that page does relate to the Jepsen issues. Just because part of that elastic manual is about issues other than Jepsen does not mean his answer is not relevant to the question - it clearly is.